# Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'PHP-php'

Tags: wordpress

When I trying to load my wordpress site, Its giving an error "  Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'PHP-php' ".

1889:
1890:
1891:

Any issue with the following code.

Please help me.

Comment: One of the error code here ; 1889:<handlers>
 1890:<add name="PHP-php" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />
 1891</handlers>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may ignore this as I have managed to fix the issue. There was a duplicate collection entry of PHP and I have removed the same ;) from domains appPools config file.

Fix: 1. Go to the error occured config file : here, it is C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\yourdomain.com(domain)(2.0)(pool)

2. take a back up of that (not necessary)
3. Open in a text editor and find the section containing the website configuration:

Under this section, find  and remove the string starting with the collection entry name shown in the error (PHP-php):

5. Save the config file.

Then give it a try...!!